# Postgresql in Docker saving data in general file system

Tags: postgresql, docker, devops

I created container with command

```sh
sudo docker run --rm \
  --name selectel-pgdocker_pgdata \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=selectel \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=selectel \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=selectel \
  -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
  -d \
  -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres
```

But after, I used command

```sh
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U selectel -d selectel
```

and start creating databases and tables in `psql`. But my `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` still doesn't exist. If I create the directory manually, it is still empty. What should I do? I want to save my data in the main filesystem, not inside Docker.

Answer (score 0):

The volume you are creating is defined by `$HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, therefore you should check the contents of your  `$HOME/docker/volumes/postgres` directory, as it is the source directory mapped to your machine.

Comment: so what aim of pgdata? What difference between pgdata and volume?

Comment: and i need to save my postgresql data out of container (on server)

Comment: The internal representation of the DB is saved within dbdata, that is from postgres. The concept "volume"  is a docker abstraction of the physical hard drives, in order to make the container save files into a directory inside the container which is actually a directory in your machine.

Comment: If your configuration is correct and the container is running, the created database will be in that directory. You can check the container logs with  docker logs selectel-pgdocker_pgdata